# Length of a complex vector

Tags: vector-spaces, complex-numbers

From the definition of inner product in $\mathbb{F}^n$
$$\textbf{a}\cdot\textbf{a}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^na_{k}\overline{a_{k}}$$
Say $a_{k}=x_{k}+iy_{k}$, then 
$$\textbf{a}\cdot\textbf{a}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(x_{k}^2+y_{k}^2)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n|a_{k}|^2$$
At the same time from the definition of length of a vector 
$$||\textbf{a}||^{2}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_{k}^2=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (x_{k}+iy_{k})^{2}$$
So from here it seems that in $\mathbb{F}^n$ $\textbf{a}\cdot\textbf{a}\neq||\textbf{a}||^2$, but in class it was given as an axiom. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement $$\|a\|^2=\sum a_k^2$$ is true only for real vector spaces.  For complex vector spaces, the corresponding statement is $$\|a\|^2=\sum |a_k|^2$$
(in point of fact the latter is the correct statement for real vector spaces as well, however the two statements coincide so we may as well drop the absolute values)

For vector spaces over a general field, the corresponding statement is $$\|a\|^2={\langle a,a\rangle}$$